# mysqlpp's (Tangensoft) insertfrom with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: c++, bulkinsert, on-duplicate-key, mysqlpp

I searched a lot in the docs, but can't find an example or explanation upon the (detailed!) usage of Query::InsertPolicy in conjunction to the mass insertion function "insertfrom()".
It just seems to limit things like packet size or likewise, but how can I get a large insert (greater then 1MB) with about 15000 rows to have an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` working?

I only find options for chopping the INSERT statement into smaller chunks, but the command always seems to be
`INSERT (...) VALUES (...)`
What I need is an insertfrom() call for
`INSERT (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

^5
Synopsis

expectation: mysqlpp's insertfrom() to use `ON DULPICATE KEY`

//edit:
... don't like the idea of puzzling together several "INSERT ... ON DUP KEY UPDATE" strings, limited each to 1MB and simply executing them, as it probably creates a lot of overhead in network and server.

//edit2:
WARNING: mysqlpp's mega macros "sql_create_xy(...)" are not able to be used in header files as they already instanciate some things, that the final linking will complain about being instanciated muliple times when used in headers.
This in conjuction with gcc's lack of will to allow explicit template specification outside of namespaces (espc. NOT in class def's) renders a great problem, forcing one to code the complete template implementations in the header files, where the req'ed structures made by sql_create_xy() can't be made available :-(((

Comment: meanwhile, I indeed coded the ugly way I mentioned in 1st edit, destite the issues described in 2nd edit ...
But still would like to have a clean solution for this :-)

Comment: as I expected: assembling an insert command using repeated string appending (stringstream) spoils as much CPU time as I needed to calculate the data itself, so I doubled the runtime this way.

If nobody has a useful hint, I'll no do the evil stuff and shuffle the data via sprintf into a char[] of 1MB size ...